# Custom container not drawing

Tags: vala, clutter

I've been reading about Vala over the past couple of days and decided to dive into it and make some Clutter widgets along the way. I'm currently trying to draw a private actor from my custom actor subclass. Here is a simplified version of what I've got so far.

```
public class MyContainer : Clutter.Actor, Clutter.Container {
    private Clutter.Group group;

    public MyContainer() {
        group = new Clutter.Group();
        group.set_parent(this);
    }

    public void add_actor(Clutter.Actor actor) {
        group.add_actor(actor);
        actor.show();
        set_size(group.width, group.height);

        actor_added(actor);
        queue_redraw();
    }

    public void foreach(Clutter.Callback callback) {
        group.foreach(callback);
        queue_redraw();
    }

    public override void get_preferred_height(
            float for_width,
            out float min_height_p,
            out float natural_height_p) {
        group.get_preferred_height(
                for_width,
                out min_height_p,
                out natural_height_p);
    }

    public override void get_preferred_width(
            float for_height,
            out float min_width_p,
            out float natural_width_p) {
        group.get_preferred_width(
                for_height,
                out min_width_p,
                out natural_width_p);
    }

    public override void paint() {
        group.paint();
    }

    public void remove_actor(Clutter.Actor actor) {
        group.remove_actor(actor);
        set_size(group.width, group.height);

        actor_removed(actor);
        queue_redraw();
    }

    public void sort_depth_order() {
        group.sort_depth_order();
        queue_redraw();
    }
}

int main(string [] args) {
    // Start clutter.
    var result = Clutter.init(ref args);
    if (result != Clutter.InitError.SUCCESS) {
        stderr.printf("Error: %s\n", result.to_string());
        return 1;
    }
    var stage = Clutter.Stage.get_default();

    // Build a MyCollection object.
    var myc = new MyContainer();
    myc.x = 100;
    myc.y = 100;
    var r1 = new Clutter.Rectangle();
    r1.width = 50;
    r1.height = 50;
    r1.color = Clutter.Color.from_string("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
    var t1 = new Clutter.Text();
    t1.text = "The red square.";
    t1.y = r1.height;

    // Build a Group object similar to the previous.
    var group = new Clutter.Group();
    group.x = 300;
    group.y = 100;
    var r2 = new Clutter.Rectangle();
    r2.width = 50;
    r2.height = 50;
    r2.color = Clutter.Color.from_string("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
    var t2 = new Clutter.Text();
    t2.text = "The red square.";
    t2.y = r2.height;

    // Display.
    myc.add_actor(r1);
    myc.add_actor(t1);
    group.add_actor(r2);
    group.add_actor(t2);
    stage.add_actor(myc);
    stage.add_actor(group);
    stage.show_all();

    Clutter.main();
    return 0;
}
```

The example paints the group added directly to the stage, but not the group wrapped by the custom collection that is added to the stage. How can I get this to work and what is wrong with the above?

I've been working on ubuntu 11.10 with `valac --pkg clutter-1.0 above_code_example.vala`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from buz on gnome.irc's #clutter room.
The problem is a missing override for the allocate function.